# How to check if object is still in window

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to check, if an expanded Object is still declared.

My General-Object is:

```
var test = test || {};
```

this works fine:

```
if (('test' in window)){ console.log("test is there!");  };
```

but if I expand it ...

```
test.hello = "Is this in window?";
```

the following check gives no result.

```
if (('test.hello' in window)){ console.log("test.hello shout be there!");  };
```

How can I check if test.hello is declared or not?

Comment: (No need for the double parens in those `if` conditions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property on window is `test`. The object *that* refers to has a property called `hello`.

So you can do what you're talking about like this:

```
if ('test' in window && 'hello' in test){ console.log("test.hello shout be there!");  };
```

If it's impossible for `test` or `hello` to be *falsey*, you can do that more efficiently (`in` is a bit slow, although you'd have to be doing this millions of times in a loop to care) and less awkwardly:

```
if (window.test && test.hello){ console.log("test.hello shout be there!");  };
// or
if (window.test && window.test.hello){ console.log("test.hello shout be there!");  };
```

...but again, that only works if `hello` can't be falsey (we know `test` isn't falsey, it's a non-null object reference). The falsey values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false`.

---

From your comment below:

> But how I get this to run: var testing="test.hello"; window[testing]=window[testing]&&console.log("testing there")

To do that, you'll have to split the string on the `.` and then check in a loop. A function is probably best:

```
function check(obj, str) {
    return str.split(".").every(function(part) {
        if (part in obj) {
            // The current object has the current part, grab the
            // thing it refers to for use in the next loop
            obj = obj[part];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

That uses ES5's `Array#every` function, which is shimmable on pre-ES5 engines. The `check` function works to an arbitrary depth, not just two levels.

Full example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/sudig/1/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    window.test = {hello: "testing"};

    display("Should be true: " + check(window, "test.hello"));
    display("Should be false: " + check(window, "foo.hello"));
    display("Should be false: " + check(window, "test.foo"));

    window.foo = {
      bar: {
        baz: {
          test: "foo.bar.baz.test"
        }
      }
    };

    display("Should be true: " + check(window, "foo.bar.baz.test"));

    function check(obj, str) {
        return str.split(".").every(function(part) {
            if (part in obj) {
                obj = obj[part];
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test =  test || {};
test.hello = "Is this in window?";
if ((test.hello)){ console.log("test.hello shout be there!");  }else{
console.log("boo");
}
```